# MySQL и функция из своей длл

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Есть своя, самописная, функция хэширования пароля (не суть важно что конкретно делает сама функция, больше интересен теоретический аспект вопроса). Функция вынесена в экспорт в DLL. Хочу использовать эту функцию при работе с базой данных, например

```
SELECT MyFunction( field1 ) FROM table;
```

Есть ли у MySQL (или в крайнем случае у других СУБД, к примеру, sqlite) какой-то способ импортирования и использования функций со сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно есть, при чём подобные механизмы есть почти во всех СУБД.

- Для mysql нужно будет собрать отдельную библиотеку с функцией удовлетворяющей ожиданиям mysql'я и объявить её с помощью `CREATE FUNCTION` (см. [*user defined function*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html)).
- Для sqlite'а — это вопрос одного вызова [`sqlite3_create_function`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html). Само собой над функцией нужно будет добавить свою обёртку.

Comment: Большое спасибо, дальше я сам :)